# Windows 7 crashed and displayed thin blue vertical lines on grey background. Now doesn't boot up

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

My windows 7 PC crashed and displayed thin blue vertical lines on grey background.

I have tried:

- Turning it off/on
- Press F8 when turning it on to try and trigger safe mode

All I get is a blank screen, my monitor doesn't seem to pick up the signal (via DVI cable). I can hear the computer spin up and the fans are spinning (not more/less than usual).

The specs of the machine are:

- ASUS P9X79
- Intel Core i7 3930K, Six Core, 3.2GHz, 12MB Cache
- 16GB DDR3
- Enermax Modu82+ 625w PSU
- 1GB Sapphire HD6670 ULTIMATE
- Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit

I thought it was the graphics card but thought booting into safe mode would have bypassed it. What else could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was your graphics card drivers, safe mode would bypass it. The vertical lines you described, if you see these right at boot (before windows), then it's probably your Graphics Card hardware. If you have another cheap card, or on-board video, try that it it should resolve your issue of accessing windows.

If that works, your card is done and you need a new one.

Comment: Yes this sounds like a bad video card.

Comment: Tried another graphics card and it's working, so faulty card.